# I want specific pattern

Tags: java

Here is my code which i had tried.

```
    int rows2 = 5;
    for (int i = 1;i<=rows2; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j<rows2; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for (int j = 1;j<=i; j++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
```

output for above code

```
    *
   **
  ***
 ****
*****
```

I want specific output as follow (Numbers insted of stars)

```
    1
   12
  123
 1234
12345
```

Comment: Your code does not produce that output. There's no asterisk in your code.

Comment: your code is correct as you want, it print numbers instead of stars

Comment: Where is astrisk in your code ?

Comment: Sorry here i made a change.

Comment: check my answer it might help you bro.

Comment: The original code of this question did print numbers instead of stars, except you explicitly coded it to print spaces between the numbers. Just remove that space, and you got what you wanted. Why is this is problem?

Comment: The link explains different patterns https://www.journaldev.com/24605/pyramid-pattern-programs-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
int numRows = 5;

for (int r=0; r < numRows; ++r) {
    for (int i=0; i < numRows-r-1; ++i) System.out.print(" ");
    for (int j=0; j < r+1; ++j) System.out.print(j+1);
    System.out.println();
}

    1
   12
  123
 1234
12345
```

The logic here is the for each row, we print `numRows - r` spaces, where `r` is the row number, starting with a value of 1.  Then, we print numbers from 1 to the row number, in order, to fill up the remainder of that row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public class Pattern 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        int rows2 = 5;
        for (int i = 1;i<=rows2; i++) 
        {
            for (int j = i; j<rows2; j++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 1;j<=i; j++) {
                System.out.print(j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did i get -1 ??

Comment: Code only answers are low quality.  You should be aiming to **teach** the beginner / learner, not just give them something to cut and paste.